# Profinite Topology

Tags: profinite-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $V$ and $W$ be pseudovarieties of finite groups. For a finite inverse monoid $M$,  the $V$-kernel of $M$  is defined to be the intersection of all sets $f^{−1}(1)$,  $f$ is a relational morphism from $M$ into a finite group  $G\in V$, and  denote it  by $K_V(M)$. We always have $K_V(K_W(M))\subseteq K_{V*W}(M)$ where $V*W$ is the semidirect product of  pseudovarieties. My question is ''when the reverse inclusion holds?''

Comment: My guess is that if W is locally finite then equality holds.  Probably it fails in general.

Comment: Dear Benjamin How could you guess if   $W$ is locally finite then equality holds?

Comment: Maybe it is not true but It's my feeling

Comment: If your guess is true then the equality $Sl*V*W=(Sl*V)\malcev W$ holds. I think it is weird.

Comment: Some people found J*G=JmG weird.  Perhaps I want V closed under extension and W locally finite

Comment: Dear Benjamin I could not prove your guess and I am trying to find a counter example. If your guess is true, since every pseudovariety of finite groups can be written as a union of locally finite pseudovarieties we have $Sl*V*W=(Sl*V)\malcev W$ for every extension closed pseudovarity $V$. Is there any such example that the equality does not hold?

Comment: So my guess is wrong.  I don't know a countered ample but believe them to exist.

Comment: In my paper with Delgado, Fernandes and Margolis 
ON SEMIGROUPS WHOSE IDEMPOTENT-GENERATED SUBSEMIGROUP IS APERIODIC we prove that if you take V to be the pseudovariety of abelian groups, then the iteration of taking $K_V()$ on an inverse monoid $M$ results in the idempotents iff $M$ has solvable maximal subgroups.  So if you could find an inverse monoid with solvable maximal subgroups which does not belong to $SL*G_{sol}$ then you would have a counterexample.  It is widely conjectured such inverse monoids exist but nobody has constructed them.